# Connecting raspberry to java serverSocket

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to make raspberry listen to the java socket server. I run the server code with eclipse and then log in to raspberry desktop and run client.jar. When i run client.jar it does not connect to my server and does not throw any errors. It just 'stays' in the Lxterminal forever and does nothing.

Server

```
int port = 6666;
        Inet4Address add = (Inet4Address) Inet4Address.getLocalHost();
        System.err.println(add);
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6666, 1, add);

            Socket client = server.accept();
            System.err.println("acc");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                while (true){
                    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                    String line = read.readLine();
                    out.writeUTF(line);
                    out.flush();
            System.err.println(in.readUTF());
            }
```

Client

```
int port = 6666;
        Socket server = new Socket("My ip", port);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());

        while (true)
        {
            String msg = in.readUTF();
            if (msg.contentEquals("close"))
                server.close();
            else if (msg.equals("forward"))
            {
            out.writeUTF("I go forward master");
            out.flush();
        }
```

UPDATE:
I have resolved this problem few seconds ago.My firewall was blocking any connection so the raspberry couldn't connect. 
Solution: Go to firewall and network connection and turn it off for private and public connections. I am using Win10

Comment: "it does not connect to my server without throwing errors" - What *errors*?

Comment: @JacobG. i said that it does not throw any errors. I mean just kind of freeze without doing anything.

Comment: I edited (pending) the question to say "it does not connect to my server and does not throw any errors" - I think this says what you intended to say, a little more clearly.  You can revert my change if you disagree.

Comment: You should use `null` as the bind-address for the server socket, not any local IP address. NB You are trying to make the Raspberry *connect* to the server socket. It's the server socket that is doing the listening.

Comment: @user207421 You say that i shoul change the client to connect to a null ip address? Is the server code good for now or I need to change it too. Btw, does the raspberry need a static ip in order to connect to the server ?

Comment: No, I said 'you should use `null` as the bind-address for the server socket'. Please read what I actually wrote, and don't expect me to just repeat myself.

Comment: @user207421 I am sorry . I didn't understand. And i don't understand now too but does not matter, I 've solved the problem. Thanks for help!